# prefetch_related not working when using SerializedMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have four levels of nested models, the `Company` > `Division` > `Team` > `TeamMember`. The following code serializes everything correctly.

My issue is when trying to use `prefetch_related` in views.py. Based on the SQL queries reported in the debugger, it looks like the `Division` and `Team` tables are being prefetched correctly, but there are hundreds of extra SQL queries for the `TeamMember` table.

I suspect the issue might be that within `CompanySerializer`, I am using a `SerializerMethodField` to get `Teams`. Could it be that using `Team.objects.filter(division__company=obj)` is not compatible with prefetching?

models.py

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey("Team", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Team(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300)
    division = models.ForeignKey("Division", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Division(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=300)
```

serializers.py

```
class TeamMemberSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TeamMember
        fields = '__all__'


class TeamSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    teammembers = TeamMemberSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source="teammember_set")

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = '__all__'

class DivisionSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    teams = TeamSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source="team_set")

    class Meta:
        model = Division
        fields = '__all__'

class CompanySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    # I suspect the issue might here. I wish to return the company's divisions AND
    # teams in this fashion. When the SerializedMethodField is removed, the spurious
    # SQL queries are eliminated.
    divisions = DivisionSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source="division_set")
    teams = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_teams(self, obj):
        teams = Team.objects.filter(division__company=obj)
        serializer = TeamSerializer(teams, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

views.py

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return CompanySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Company.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch("division_set", queryset=Division.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch("team_set", queryset=Team.objects.prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch("teammember_set")
                )
            ))
        ))
```